# Connect to AWS s3 from on-premise via site-to-site VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

We have a hybrid model with on-premise connected to AWS via a site-to-site VPN. There is a need to download data from s3 to on-premise in a way that the traffic will go from on-premise to AWS and back without going to the open Internet for security considerations. I.e. similar to this:
`on-prem --VPN--> AWS private subnet --> s3 endpoint --> s3`

This schema works with interface endpoints since they generate private DNS names which can be used to call from on-premise, but the s3 endpoint is a gateway endpoint, not an interface endpoint, so it doesn't generate private DNS names.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In February 2021, AWS released S3 PrivateLink Interface Endpoints which are different to the S3 Gateway Endpoints.

The difference is that S3 Interface Endpoints resolve to private VPC IP addresses and are routeable from outside the VPC (e.g via VPN, Direct Connect, Transit Gateway etc).  S3 Gateway Endpoints use public IP ranges and are only routeable from resources within the VPC.

Interface Endpoints mean you can route to S3 buckets from your on-premise network via your VPN and one or more subnets without needing a proxy in the VPC, and without traversing the public Internet.

Refer to the [blog announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-privatelink-for-amazon-s3-now-available/) and the [S3 privatelink user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html) for more details.

Comment: Be aware that using this method to transfer large amounts of data into cloud will incur costs that would not be applicable if it were transferred via a public route https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/pricing/ (and potentially Transit Gateway charges as well depending on your configuration)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [VPC endpoints documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) S3 doesn't provide direct access through a VPN:

> Endpoint connections cannot be extended out of a VPC. Resources on the other side of a VPN connection, a VPC peering connection, an AWS Direct Connect connection, or a ClassicLink connection in your VPC cannot use the endpoint to communicate with resources in the endpoint service.

However, you could route the [Amazon S3 IP address ranges](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-find-ip-address-ranges/) through your VPN connection to the VPC and explicitly allow access to the S3 buckets for your VPN's public IP addresses in the bucket policy and deny everything else.

Please note that the Amazon S3 IP address ranges are subject to change.